# DataFrame to GeoDataFrame Error: could not convert string to float

Tags: geopandas, spatial-join, jupyter-notebook

I have two Excel sheets with x und y coordinates (EPSG 4326) and several other attributes. My aim is to match both Excel sheets via the coordinates (geopandas.sjoin_nearest). I try to convert the coordinates into float with

```
gdf1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df1,geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(df1.x.astype('float16'), df1.y.astype('float16')))
```

but then I get "could not convert into string". I already used "df1['x'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['x'], errors='coerce')", but it does not get any better. How can I solve this problem?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[22], line 26
     18 df2.to_excel("C:\\Users\\...", index = False)

---> 26 gdf1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df1,geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(df1.x.astype('float16'), df1.y.astype('float16')))

   (...)
     
     37 result_match = gdf1.sjoin_nearest(gdf2, how = 'right', max_distance = 500)


File ~\.conda\envs\geo_env\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py:431, in BaseBlockManager.astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    428 elif using_copy_on_write():
    429     copy = False
--> 431 return self.apply(
    432     "astype",
    433     dtype=dtype,
    434     copy=copy,
    435     errors=errors,
    436     using_cow=using_copy_on_write(),
    437 )

File ~\.conda\envs\geo_env\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py:364, in BaseBlockManager.apply(self, f, align_keys, **kwargs)
    362         applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    363     else:
--> 364         applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    365     result_blocks = extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
    367 out = type(self).from_blocks(result_blocks, self.axes)

File ~\.conda\envs\geo_env\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py:758, in Block.astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, using_cow, squeeze)
    755         raise ValueError("Can not squeeze with more than one column.")
    756     values = values[0, :]  # type: ignore[call-overload]
--> 758 new_values = astype_array_safe(values, dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
    760 new_values = maybe_coerce_values(new_values)
    762 refs = None

File ~\.conda\envs\geo_env\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\astype.py:237, in astype_array_safe(values, dtype, copy, errors)
    234     dtype = dtype.numpy_dtype
    236 try:
--> 237     new_values = astype_array(values, dtype, copy=copy)
    238 except (ValueError, TypeError):
    239     # e.g. _astype_nansafe can fail on object-dtype of strings
    240     #  trying to convert to float
    241     if errors == "ignore":

File ~\.conda\envs\geo_env\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\astype.py:182, in astype_array(values, dtype, copy)
    179     values = values.astype(dtype, copy=copy)
    181 else:
--> 182     values = _astype_nansafe(values, dtype, copy=copy)
    184 # in pandas we don't store numpy str dtypes, so convert to object
    185 if isinstance(dtype, np.dtype) and issubclass(values.dtype.type, str):

File ~\.conda\envs\geo_env\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\astype.py:133, in _astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
    129     raise ValueError(msg)
    131 if copy or arr.dtype == object or dtype == object:
    132     # Explicit copy, or required since NumPy can't view from / to object.
--> 133     return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
    135 return arr.astype(dtype, copy=copy)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '8,9594966'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share the excel files?

Comment: Here is a short example from the excel sheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decimal separator

I think you live in a country with comma separator instead of point as i can see from your screenshot.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator

Python needs points and doesn't understand that '8,9594966' is '8.9594966'.

```
str.replace(",", ".")
```

or

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'data.csv', decimal=',')

df = pd.read_excel(r'data.xlsx', decimal=',')
```

You have to change **" , "** to **" . "** bofeore you convert to float.